# Что лучше использовать для отображения списков?

Tags: android

Мне посоветовали использовать RecyclerView для списков которые тянут данные с сети. А как быть с спискам которые используют кнопоки или текстовые поля. Есть ли смысл пихать повсюду Recycler? И если нет то чем лучше пользоваться в простых случаях?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` следует использовать в тех случаях, когда количество элементов списка **заранее неизвестно**, и элементы списка добавляются **динамически** в процессе работы программы.

А если же, например, Вам необходимо осуществить прокрутку списка с **несколькими** кнопками, количество которых **известно заранее**, то в данном случае разумным решением будет использовать `ScrollView`.

Comment: А как быть со списком кнопок которые по горизонтали? Просто вешать на них scroll и все?

Comment: @ТарасЖупник, Не очень понимаю, о чем Вы. Если у Вас есть заранее известное количество кнопок, то Вы можете обернуть их, например, в `LinearLayout`, который, в свою очередь будет потомком `ScrollView`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Это меня и интересовало

Comment: А если количество известно заранее, элементов 1000 штук? Советуете ScrollView?

Comment: Какой `ScrollView`? katso верно написал - если количество вьюшек известно заранее, но их очень много, вы представляете, что это за разметка будет? Лучше использовать `ListView` для списков с известной длиной. Так как, ставить слушатели на все кнопки - говнокод. А с `ListView` можно поставить один и все это дело оживить. ИМХО, для списков с неизвестной длиной подошел бы и `ListView`.

Comment: не согласен насчет ScrollView и *заранее известного кол-ва эжлементов*. Как сказал @katso, если элементов будет `over9000`, То будет у вас слайдшоу, если с ООМ не упадет.

Comment: Надо использовать `ListView`, потому что выбор `ScrollView` убьет Ваше быстродейтсвие.
Про `RecyclerView` - согласен

Comment: @katso, Нет, не советую. И не советовал, кстати. Может быть, я немного неясно выразился. Выделю-ка слово **несколькими** в ответе.

Comment: А про `ListView` – я считаю, что его в данное время вообще использовать не стоит. Ему на смену сами знаете что пришло.

Comment: Протестую против неверного ответа...

Answer (score 2):

Определенно стоит использовать RecycleView + CardView, сможете добавить каждому элементу и кнопочки, и тексты без проблем. В качестве примера приведу разметку для каждого элемента списка:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/Wide"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageTask"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Wrap"
            android:id="@+id/contentTask"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin1"
            style="@style/Full"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/createData"
                style="@style/Wrap"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/completed"
                style="@style/Wrap"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Completed" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

И вот так будет выглядеть разметка активити со списком

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    style="@style/Full"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/Fab"
    android:src="@drawable/add_icon"
    />
```